# Difference between module.exports and exports.functionName in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get rid of `/api` prefix in my API requests. Right now it's like this:

```
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

But I don't know why it's not working when I'm changing it to this:

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Does Cloud Functions have some issue with `module.exports` here? Or it's not related to Firebase and more to Javascript in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the way that Cloud Functions works when you work with the Firebase SDK and CLI.  You must name your function in the exports of index.js, and that name always becomes part of the path generated URL.  You can't eliminate this name from the final path.

Your alternative is to put Firebase Hosting in front of Cloud Functions and have it rewrite the Hosting URLs to Cloud Functions endpoints.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) shows you how to get started with this.  You will have to use some sort of wildcard pattern to [rewrite entire paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), if that's what you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: One more question: so it's perfectly normal to have `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-name/functions/list` just one function called `api` on the list then (in case I wouldn't apply your solution)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you have one function exported, then you will see one entry in the console.  It doesn't matter if that's an express app with multiple routes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. I see one entry in console even though it has multiple routes. If that's how it's supposed to be then all good.